# Send wp post title on an email with onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, email

I am sending an email to my outlook account every time the `<a>` is clicked. I want that the message has the title of the wordpress post where the link was clicked, however, it is not printed in the email. It's not recognizing `the_title();` to get post title. Other problem is that the email is going into the spam folder.

**how to fix this?**

```
<a href="#" onclick="callFunction();">Report</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callFunction(){
        <?php  
            $message = ''.the_title();
            $to = "my@outlook.com";
            $subject = "Expired post report";
            $from = "reporting@website.com"; 
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are mixing 2 languages JavaScript works in the browser PHP works on the server you cannot use PHP as an onclick function the most you could  do is post information to a server with the information needed

Comment: The easiest way I find of leaving data from PHP for JavaScript to use is leaving it as an attribute, like this; <html data-title="<?= $the_title ?>"></html>

Comment: Regarding the email going into the spam folder, that might be because of your other problem with the blank message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Javascript, client side execution, to call a PHP function, a server side execution, you will need to create a very small API using ajax. If you include jQuery into your project, you could send Javascript variables to a PHP file and send the mail using PHP.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/file/mail.php",
    data: {
        message : "<?php echo the_title(); ?>",
        subject : "Expired post report"
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

PHP file called mail.php:

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$to = "my@outlook.com",
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$headers = "From: reporting@website.com";

echo mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

mail() returns true if it was successful, so the Javascript function will alert true / false.

Comment: It works! I get the name of the post by email! Thank you very much, this is very interesting. However, the email is still going into the spam folder. Any clue about it? Thanks

Comment: Also, the messenger is not printed as "reporting@website.com" but something alike to my web host account. EDIT: Just a mispelling mistake, it is `$_REQUEST['headers'];` not `$_REQUEST['header'];`

Comment: Btw, not much important, but is there a way to avoid more than one request to this ajax function?

Comment: You might want to hard code your 'to' email address to prevent anybody from using your script to send random spam emails to anybody.

Comment: Yes, to achieve that i've quit the `'to'` data declaration from the ajax function, and in mail.php i've replaced the `'to'` request instead a php sentence on mail.php to get the email of the wp site administrator: `$to = ''.get_option( 'admin_email' );` so no one can see the email adress

Comment: Have you tried adding some headers? Something like:

``$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Your name <$from>\r\n";``

..and if that's not working then try the PHPMailer class. And if that's still not working then talk to your web host and ask to verify the mail server and the headers and settings it's using, etc.

Comment: Well, i've added all the possible headers i can and it's still going to spam. Outlook has already blocked any email coming from my host, or so it looks, as emails stopped arriving to it. I don't know if that will happen to Gmail so i have to try PHPMailer class. As no longer can be done in my issue without PHPMailerClass or host mail data, i consider yours as the right answer.